# Drag & Sort using Kendo UI

Tags: jquery-ui, kendo-ui, telerik

I want to implement similar functionality to the jQuery UI Draggable & Sortable, but using Kendo UI.

This should allow me to drag from a list of options and place them within a sortable list.

Here is the jQuery UI functionality: http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable

I want 2 panels, one with items that can be dragged and the other containing the dragged items. The closest thing I could find on Kendo UI is: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/sortable/linkedlists, but the items in the first list (on the left) are sortable and this moves the item from the first list.

I have looked at all of the Kendo UI samples on Teleriks website, but I cannot see any examples of how to do this.

---

Update:

I am now part way there. I have 2 sortable lists and I have added code to stop the 'draggable' items from sortable. However, when I drag an item to the 'sortable' list, it disappears from the 'draggable' list.

Here's the code I'm using to stop the items being sortable:

```
start: function() {
  $("#draggable li").each(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("sortable");
  });
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kgjertsen/r4xmLevq/

Anyone able to tell me how to stop the items from disappearing?

Comment: Check if this is like you want: http://dojo.telerik.com/OQEne

Comment: This keeps adding multiple items when you sort.

Comment: Sure, I have updated: http://dojo.telerik.com/OQEne/2

Comment: This is close. However, as per the Telerik sample, I want 2 panels. One has the items that can be dragged and the other has the items that have been dragged and are sortable.

Comment: I see. Well, I answered your first issue, which was to have a kendo widget with similar behaviour of the jQuery UI's. Now you update your question with another requirement, which I think you can give a try starting on from the solution I have provided(and the kendo's double lists own demo), don't you think ?

Comment: I edited my question to make it fully explain what I wanted. Telerik supplies samples of fixed or disabled items: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/sortable/filter-disable

Comment: Yes, I see that example. What I'm suggesting is that you give a try with the code I provided and the telerik's example. I think that with my code you're totally able to achieve this by yourself now. I can't help further if you don't show me you're trying something.

Comment: I'll look at this, using what you have provided.

Comment: Nice, then post any problem you have, and we work on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of investigation, it turns out that you cannot link draggable with sortable, as you can with jQuery. You need to drop the item into the container, then sort it from its default place, which is at the bottom.

Telerik justify this with a statement saying that they cannot implement this behaviour as the controls cannot know about each other, as this is bad practice.

Personally, I think this is terrible and the functionality would be a great addition to the Kendo UI library.